# re search when square brackets are present

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am trying to parse through a string of known format to obtain variables for speed and direction (basically recreating sscanf functionality), an example string shown below

```
s = 'speed: 100.0, direction[ 12 ]'
```

However, the square brackets after direction are causing me problems. I have tried

```
checker=re.search('speed: (?P<speed>[-+]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?), direction\[ (?P<direc>\d) \]',s)
print(f"[{checker['speed']},{checker['direc']}]")
```

adding \ before the square brackets as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74477176/4879524

However, this is not working, and I am unsure how to proceed. If I remove the square brackets from the string it works fine, but I wish to avoid doing that if possible.

My regex knowledge is about 4 hours old so it may be a very simple fix. **I cannot use parse module as an alternative sadly**

**WITH SQUARE BRACKETS** - There is no match so...

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

**WITHOUT SQUARE BRACKETS**

```
s = 'speed: 100.0, direction 12'

checker = re.search('speed: (?P<speed>[-+]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?), direction (?P<direc>\d)',s)
print(f"[{checker['speed']},{checker['direc']}]")

>>[100.0,1] # (yes I forgot the + when I wrote it out in stack so here's the answer without the +, you can see that's not causing my error)
```

Comment: Explain "not working". What happens? Show an error message (if any) completely as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `direction\[?\s*(?P<direc>\d+)\s*\]?`:

```
checker=re.search('speed: (?P<speed>[-+]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?), direction\[?\s*(?P<direc>\d+)\s*\]?',s)
print(f"[{checker['speed']},{checker['direc']}]")
```

Output:

```
# s = 'speed: 100.0, direction[ 12 ]'
[100.0,12]

# s = 'speed: 100.0, direction 12'
[100.0,12]
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error even after copying and pasting your code in curiously...

Comment: @Jack. I fixed my answer. Now it works for both case.

Answer (score 2):

The bug has actually got nothing to do with the square brackets.

You need to replace this:

```
(?P<direc>\d)
```

With this:

```
(?P<direc>\d+)
```

So in other words, the full line of code becomes:

```
checker=re.search('speed: (?P<speed>[-+]?(\d+(\.\d*)?|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?), direction\[ (?P<direc>\d+) \]',s)
```

More specifically, your regex was only matching against **one digit** between the square brackets (e.g. `"[ 1 ]"`), rather than one-or-more digits between the square brackets (e.g. the actual example you gave above, of `"[ 12 ]"`)

Comment: Note for future: You said "If I remove the square brackets from the string it works fine", but you didn't actually give a code example of this happening -- doing so would been helpful for everyone involved :)

Comment: Have edited it to include the results, you should be able to see the effect of the square brackets now, sorry I wrote this whilst eating my lunch and my stomach comes before my brain

Comment: @Jack Your **"WITHOUT SQUARE BRACKETS"** edit doesn't *just* remove the square brackets. You also removed the spaces around the number. That's why it matched.

Comment: To be more precise, given this input string: `s = 'speed: 100.0, direction 12'`, that regex is matching up to the last character: `s = 'speed: 100.0, direction 1'`. It's not matching against the whole string. You can see this because the capture group for `direc` is `1` instead of `12`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that finds (decimal) numbers in a string

```
import re
s = 'speed: 100.0, direction[ 12 ]'
# find (decimal) numbers in string. Only works if order is fixed
speed, direction = re.findall(r'\d+\.*\d*', s)

# output: 100.0, 12
speed = float(speed)  # cast to number
direction = float(direction)  # cast to number
```